# Function to apply an Eigen transformation to vectors using either floats or doubles

Tags: c++, transformation, eigen

I have an Eigen transformation `t` defined using doubles. The following examples do work:

```
Vector3d d_point, t_d_point, d_vector, t_d_vector;  // Initialization not shown
Vector3f f_point, t_f_point, f_vector, t_f_vector;

// Transforming points
t_d_point = t * d_point;                                 
t_f_point = t.template cast<float>() * f_point;          

// Transforming vectors
t_d_vector = t.linear() * d_vector;                      
t_f_vector = t.template cast<float>().linear() * f_vector;
```

If I declare the function

```
template <typename Transform, typename Derived>
inline auto transformPoint(const Transform & t, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> & point) {
    return t.template cast<typename Derived::Scalar>() * point;
}
```

the following works:

```
t_d_point = transformPoint(t, d_point);
t_f_point = transformPoint(t, f_point);
```

However, the vector version

```
template <typename Transform, typename Derived>
inline auto transformVector(const Transform & t, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> & vector) {
    return t.template cast<typename Derived::Scalar>().linear() * vector;
}
```

works when the cast is not necessary (both the transformation and the vector are defined using doubles):

```
t_d_vector = transformVector(t * d_vector);
```

but fails when the cast is needed, returning garbage in the result:

```
t_f_vector = transformVector(t * f_vector);
```

Given that `t.template cast<float>().linear() * f_vector` does work, what is a proper declaration for the `transformVector()` function?

Comment: I found that using ```t.linear().template cast<typename Derived::Scalar>() * vector;``` works, and it's perfectly valid for my project.
But it doesn't answer my specific question.

Comment: Looks like an [`auto` related pitfall](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html). The Geometry module in many cases returns by value which makes `t.template cast<float>().linear() * f_vector` an expression template depending on a temporary.

Comment: Yes, digging a bit it seems that Transform::cast() creates a temporary variable, while Matrix::cast() produces an Eigen expression.